# Python — check if a string contains Cyrillic characters

Tags: python, string, cyrillic

How to check whether a string contains Cyrillic characters?

E.g.

```
>>> has_cyrillic('Hello, world!')
False
>>> has_cyrillic('Привет, world!')
True
```

Comment: Strangely this question was not tagged [tag:cyrillic] until now...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) supports Unicode properties, along with a few short forms.

```
>>> regex.search(r'\p{IsCyrillic}', 'Hello, world!')
>>> regex.search(r'\p{IsCyrillic}', 'Привет, world!')
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='П'>
>>> regex.search(r'\p{IsCyrillic}', 'Hello, wёrld!')
<regex.Match object; span=(8, 9), match='ё'>
```

Answer (score 34):

You can use a regular expression to check if a string contains characters in the `а-я, А-Я` range:

```
import re 

def has_cyrillic(text):
    return bool(re.search('[а-яА-Я]', text))
```

---

Alternatively, you can match the [whole Cyrillic script range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode):

```
def has_cyrillic(text):
    return bool(re.search('[\u0400-\u04FF]', text))
```

This will also match letters of the extended Cyrillic alphabet (e.g. ё, Є, ў).

Comment: Oops. `has_cyrillic('Hello, wёrld!')` is `False`.

Comment: In case anyone is looking for an R equivalent `grepl(pattern = '[\u0400-\u04FF]', x = text)` will do the job.

Comment: As for me it works fine

Answer (score 5):

Suggesting a method, faster than the discussed ones here.

**Approach#1:**

```
len("экономия3r4".encode("ascii", "ignore")) > len ("экономия3r4")

246 ns ± 7.76 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Would print "True" if there is a Cyrillic character

**Approach#2:**

Discussed in earlier post by Max

```
import re

def has_cyrillic(text):
    return bool(re.search('[а-яА-Я]', text))

has_cyrillic("экономия3r4")

929 ns ± 20.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: there must be `len("экономия3r4".encode("ascii", "ignore")) < len("экономия3r4")` to check if its cyrillic

Comment: Approach #1 is great performance-wise, but it takes into consideration all non-ascii characters (e.g Chinese, Hindi) instead of only considering Cyrillic.

Answer (score -7):

You could create a `set` containing the cyrillic letters and just check each character of the string:

```
cyrillic_letters = {....} # fill it with the cyrillic letters

def has_cyrillic(text):
    for c in text:
        if c in cyrillic_letters:
            return True
    return False
```