# Adding different elements to the list with conditions Python - return a tuple

Tags: python

I have a task to write a function that adds "Hello, " and "Привет" if a name in the list is English or Russian and then returns a tuple. For example, we have ["Mary", "Kate", "Маша", "Alex"]. Our function should return a tuple like this: ('Hello, Mary', 'Hello, Kate', 'Привет, Маша', 'Hello, Alex). I have no idea how to achieve this. I can add Hello to all elements, but what to do with this Привет I don't know.

What I came up with so far...

Please help!

```
def name(my_list):
    for x in my_list:
        new_lis = ["Hello, " + x for x in my_list]
    new_lis1 = tuple(new_lis)
    print(new_lis1)

name(my_list)
```

Comment: How do you know if a name is Russian?

Comment: If it is written with letters from different alphabet, not "abcdefg.." but "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщэюя".

Comment: You can use `x.isalpha()` to test if the name is plain ASCII, but depending on your actual data, this may not be enough.

Comment: I think @user1558604 means "how would YOU determine, in the code, whether a string is in Russian or English?" Your answer to yourself (in regular English or Russian) will help you write the code itself (i.e. in Python).

Comment: Are you unsure how to *use* a condition to select ``"Hello"`` versus ``"Привет"``, or are you unsure how *define* a condition to check for English versus Russian names?

Answer (score 1):

this isn't really the type of website, were you post your question and someone else finds the answer for you - but you are in luck, and someone had the exact [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255244/python-check-if-a-string-contains-cyrillic-characters) before.

Following the answers in the linked thread, you could do something like:

```py
def salutation_name(name):
    if all([c in '[а-яА-Я]' for c in name]):
        return f'Привет {name}'
    else:
        return f'Hello {name}'

names = ["Mary", "Kate", "Маша", "Alex"]

print([salutation_name(name) for name in names])
```

Comment: Hi PD7. You mean the question is a duplicate. If you just leave a comment to that extent, citing the dupe target, other [users will vote to close as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

Comment: Well it wasn't a duplicate, it was just the same problem - thanks for reminding me however.

Comment: PD7: essentially it is a dupe, the rest is trivial (anyway it can be done with a list-comprehension). Hey by the way you could change your function to `salutation(text)` and have it directly return `"Привет"/"Hello"` according as `text` has any Cyrillic characters or not.

Comment: Yeah - I was so focused on using part of the other thread as answer, that I completely overlooked that ...

Comment: Here's a nicer cleaner decomposition, also doesn't need regex: `def salutation_name(name):
    if [all(c in '[а-яА-Я]') for c in name]:
        return f'Привет {name}'
    else:
        return f'Hello {name}'

for name in names:
   print salutation_name(name`

Comment: No problem, just wanted to figure out a nice clean decomposition. Also I wonder whether the regex version is faster than non-regex (EDIT: neglecting the once-off overhead to import re and compile the regex) EDIT: on a list length O(N) in general, not just a short list of four names